# Graphics2D and GUI: ArrayList of methods, method reference error

Tags: java, arraylist, awt, graphics2d, method-reference

Imagining I have an arrayList of three JButtons: b_line, b_rect, b_oval, whose functionalities are very similar - they draw line/rectangle/oval on the JFrame.

Instead of writing actionListener for all three of them manually, I am thinking about using ArrayList to assign their actionListeners - so create an arraylist of Graphic2D draw methods, like this:

```
{drawLine, drawRect, drawOval}
```

Below is my code:

```
ArrayList<Consumer<Void>> draws = new ArrayList<>();
draws.add(Graphics2D::drawLine);
```

The error occurs saying that drawline is static method and it should not be used in this context.

How can I modify the method reference to support the drawLine method? Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[drawLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawLine(int,int,int,int)) does not conform to the signature of the abstract method in [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

You created a List of `Consumer<Void>` objects, so you have to pass in `Consumer<Void>` objects.  The Consumer class, like all functional interfaces, has exactly one abstract method:

```
public void accept(T argument)
```

Your method reference must match that *signature.*  A method’s signature is its return type and its argument types.  So, each of your method references must be one of the following:

- a static method with exactly the same return type and the same arguments
- a non-static method, with the same return type, which belongs to a type that matches the first argument of the above method, and whose remaining arguments match the remaining arguments of the above method.

The `accept` method of Consumer has only one argument, so there are zero “remaining arguments.”  Therefore, your method reference must be one of the following:

- a static method which returns `void` and which accepts one argument of type `Void` (since your List requires `Consumer<Void>` objects)
- a non-static method belonging to class `Void` which which returns `void` and which expects zero arguments

Obviously, Graphics.drawLine conforms to neither of those.  drawLine does return void, but it certainly does not take a `Void` argument.  In fact, it requires four arguments, so it cannot qualify as a `Consumer`, ever.

You will have to define your own functional interface.  For instance:

```
public interface RectangularShapeDrawer {
    void draw(Graphics g, int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);
}
```

Then use that type in your List:

```
List<RectangularShapeDrawer> drawers = new ArrayList<>();
drawers.add(Graphics::drawLine);
drawers.add(Graphics::drawRect);
drawers.add(Graphics::drawOval);
```

In my opinion, since the Graphics.draw* methods are just one line of code each, you are better off writing three separate ActionListeners.

Comment: Love this, especially the last line 1+

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possibility.  I would use an enum rather than an ArrayList.  I had to design a new Functional interface for this to work.  Of course, you can rename anything.  If the active enum type is not set, nothing will paint.  You can also chose to null it out in `process` after each button press.

```
enum  Draws { OVAL(Graphics2D::drawOval),
       LINE(Graphics2D::drawLine),
       RECT(Graphics2D::drawRect);
       
       private IntPentaFunction fnc;
       private Draws(IntPentaFunction fnc) {
           this.fnc = fnc;
       }
       public IntPentaFunction getFnc() {
           return fnc;
       }
}
public class ConsumerGraphics extends JPanel {
    IntPentaFunction active;
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    
    interface IntPentaFunction {
        public void apply(Graphics2D g2d, int a, int b, int c,
                int d);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500,500);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConsumerGraphics().start();
    }
    
    public void start() {
       
        JButton b_oval = new JButton("Oval");
        b_oval.addActionListener((ae)->process(Draws.OVAL));
        JButton b_line = new JButton("Line");
        b_line.addActionListener((ae)->process(Draws.LINE));
        JButton b_rect = new JButton("Rectangle");
        b_rect.addActionListener((ae)->process(Draws.RECT));
        add(b_oval);
        add(b_line);
        add(b_rect);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
        
    }
    public void process(Draws type) {
        // do other stuff in prep for draw
       
        active = type.getFnc();
        repaint();
        // do any cleanup
    }
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (active == null) {
            return;
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        active.apply(g2d,100,100,200,200);
        
    }
}
```